# Unable to delete from database in a RESTful web application

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to delete some rows (older than 5 minutes) from a table in a RESTful web application like so (startTime is the table column containing creation time of each row in the yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss format):

```
String query =  "SELECT t FROM abc t WHERE DATE_ADD(CAST(t.startTime AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 5 DAY) < NOW()";
    List<abc> res = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    for (abc t:res) {
        em.remove(t);// em is the entitymanager
    }
```

I get an exception in the value I'm using as the interval:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   5 near line 1, column 91 [SELECT t FROM com.pack1.abc t WHERE
>   DATE_ADD(CAST(t.startTime AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 5 DAY) < NOW()]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this is a 'rest' thing...

Comment: I guess you are using mysql if yes then hibernate does not support DATE_ADD function.

Comment: read this http://www.javawebdevelop.com/500856/

Comment: @thecoshman, removed the "rest" tag.

Comment: @Orion, thanks, though I won't be able to mark your comment as an answer till it's just a comment.